# Light problem with shade smooth

Tags: light, lighting

Hello there fellow blender people!

I am new to blender and I have this problem with light... When I shine light on a "shade smooth" wall trim, it does this weird thing. I don't know how to fix it. Can someone please help? [image]

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I found a solution, Normals > Autosmooth > ON
the problem is now non-existent...[image]